# Count points from shapefile within raster cells

Tags: r, raster

Is it in some way possible to count the number of points from a shapefile within each cell of a rasterfile using R?[image]

The Idea is to retrieve a dataframe containing one row for each cell in the raster and a column with the number of points within that cell while keeping the original value from the raster cell.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The usual format on this site is to show us what you tried and how it failed, rather than to simply ask for code to be written from scratch. Please take some time to read the help page, especially  ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  You should also learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(raster)
# example raster and points data
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=5)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n) * 360 - 180
y <- runif(n) * 180 - 90
xy <- cbind(x, y)

rp <- rasterize(xy, r, fun=function(x,...)length(x))
as.data.frame(rp)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question in the title "how to count the number of points from a shapefile within each cell"

```
library(rgdal)           # this package to read and manipulate shapefiles
library(raster)          # this package for rasters
shp <- readOGR("my_shape_file.shp")        # read in your points from the shape file
ras <- raster("my_raster_file")            # read in your raster
shp <- spTransform(shp, projection(ras))   # make sure that the two spatial objects share the same coordinate system
cells <- cellFromXY(ras,shp)     # find which cells the points are in
table(cells)                     # and make a table of number of occurences in each cell
```